# Wordpress wp_list_table order by date value not the string

Tags: php, wordpress

I already looked up to google but can't found the answer for wordpress `wp_list_table` to order the table by `date` value not the name,

It's sorting correctly if I show the full date, but I want to show the month and the year only not the raw dates.

Let's say:

```
2017-01-01
2017-02-01 // Correct sorting but not what I want
2017-03-01

February' 17
January' 17 // Not correct because it sort by the first string
March' 17

January' 17
February' 17 // This is what I want to look like
March' 17
```

This is my function so far to make it sort:

```
private function sort_data( $a, $b )
{
    // Set defaults
    $orderby = 'villa';
    $order = 'asc';
    // If orderby is set, use this as the sort column
    if(!empty($_GET['orderby']))
    {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    }
    // If order is set use this as the order
    if(!empty($_GET['order']))
    {
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    }
    $result = strcmp( $a[$orderby], $b[$orderby] );
    if($order === 'asc')
    {
        return $result;
    }
    return -$result;
}
```

And here is my `prepare_data` function

```
public function prepare_items()
{
    $columns    = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden     = $this->get_hidden_columns();
    $sortable   = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $data       = $this->table_data();

    usort( $data, array( &$this, 'sort_data`' ) );

    $perPage        = 20;
    $currentPage    = $this->get_pagenum();
    $totalItems     = count($data);
    $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $totalItems,
        'per_page'    => $perPage
    ) );

    $data = array_slice($data, (($currentPage - 1) * $perPage), $perPage);
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    $this->items = $data;
}
```

Actually I have a idea but I'm not sure how to done it on `wordpress`, here is my idea:

I get the raw dates from database, put it in the array and then I replace all raw dates in array with readable date after successfully sort the dates. This is the array looks like:

```
$data[] = array(
    'title' => $result['post_title'],
    'date'  => $result['available_date']
);
```

I hope I'm explain it clear enough, I really appreciate any kind of help! Cheers!

**EDIT:**

I just added this code in prepare_items, it's not working as well, after I put this now it doesn't sorted at all

```
foreach ($data AS $key) {
    if (isset($key['available_date'])) {
        $data[$i]['available_date'] = date("F Y", strtotime($key['available_date']));
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah Nevermind, I just need to move

```
foreach ($data AS $key) {
    if (isset($key['available_date'])) {
        $data[$i]['available_date'] = date("F Y", strtotime($key['available_date']));
    }
    $i++;
}
```

below `usort( $data, array( &$this, 'sort_data' ) );` in the `prepate_items`, so it'll looks like this

```
public function prepare_items()
{
    $columns    = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden     = $this->get_hidden_columns();
    $sortable   = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $data       = $this->table_data();

    usort( $data, array( &$this, 'sort_data' ) );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data AS $key) {
        if (isset($key['available_date'])) {
            $data[$i]['available_date'] = date("F Y", strtotime($key['available_date']));
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $perPage        = 20;
    $currentPage    = $this->get_pagenum();
    $totalItems     = count($data);
    $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $totalItems,
        'per_page'    => $perPage
    ) );

    $data = array_slice($data,(($currentPage-1)*$perPage),$perPage);
    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    $this->items = $data;
}
```

and now it working fine :D